# Problema al tomar el valor de un select de html5

Tags: jquery, html5, select, dom

Al recorrer un array, voy rellenando un select de forma automática, si dos valores coinciden, hago que ese valor sea el que quede como seleccionado en el select. Esto funciona pero el problema que tengo es que  al tomar el valor del select, me toma también la palabra selected( valorselected)

```
idElemento=$("#idElemento").val();
```

El valor del idElemento seria: `objJsonEle[i].idselected`

```
 $('#idElemento').append("<option value= " + objJsonEle[i].id + "selected >" + " " + objJsonEle[i].name + "</option>");
```

Comment: "El valor del idElemento seria: `objJsonEle[i].idselected` " ¿Con esto te refieres a que eso es lo que esperas obtener o lo que obtienes y no quieres? En caso de lo segundo ¿Qué esperas obtener?

Comment: dices que el valor del idElemento es `objJsonEle[i].idselected` pero luego en el append estas añadiendo `objJsonEle[i].id`

Comment: objJsonEle[i].id es una variable que puede valer por ejemplo  234. Cuando quiero acceder al contenido de la variable, en vez de ver 234, veo 234selected

Comment: Prueba a cambiar el append por: `.append("<option value='" + objJsonEle[i].id + "' selected >"+ objJsonEle[i].name + "</option>");`

Comment: Gracias, funciono bien, Publica la respuesta para que pueda valorarla por favor

Answer (score 1, accepted):

el problema lo tienes por que el value lo tienes que indicar,en tu caso, con comillas simples,quedando asi:

`$('#idElemento').append("<option value= '" + objJsonEle[i].id + "' selected >" + " " + objJsonEle[i].name + "</option>");`

de esta forma,no vas a tener ese oroblema

Answer (score 0):

Una vez rellenado el select con el valor selected deberías poder acceder a ello con

$('#idElemento').val()